# regular expressions using grep not working (\d+ in particular)

Tags: regex, grep, filenames

I am trying to write a bash script to pick out particular data files from a folder so I can make plots from them. I am trying to write a bash script that uses grep to do this. At this point I am piping the results from ls -1 into grep using a regular expression to generate a list of file names. The following are the file names I am sorting through, this pattern continues. Bolded ones are the names I would like to match with the regex: ifrontThermal.\d+

> **ifrontThermal64.00490**
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.HeI
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.HeII
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.HI
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.radFlux
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.radTens
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.u
>   ifrontThermal64.00490.uNoncool
>   **ifrontThermal64.00500**
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.HeI
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.HeII
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.HI
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.radFlux
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.radTens
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.u
>   ifrontThermal64.00500.uNoncool

These commands return nothing

```
$ (ls -1)|(grep ifrontThermal64.\d+)
$ (ls -1)|(grep ifrontThermal64\.\d+)
$ (ls -1)|(grep ifrontThermal64.[0-9]+)
```

These command returns what I expect but not what I want.

```
 $ (ls -1)|(grep ifrontThermal64.)
 $ (ls -1)|(grep ifrontThermal64.[0-9])
```

When I test the 3 ones that don't work at http://regexpal.com/ these seem to be fine.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Note that regexpal.com tests `JavaScript` regular expressions, not `bash` regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number suffixes of interest are of fixed length and all you care about is filtering out the files that have an additional extension, the following *glob* (NOT a regex, but a wildcard expression) will do:

```
ifrontThermal64.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

E.g.:

```
printf "%s\n" ifrontThermal64.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Note that globs always match against the *entire* filename, whereas `grep` performs *substring* matching by default.

As for why your approach didn't work:

- Your regex isn't quoted, so the shell's parsing 'eats' the `\`, thereby altering it.
- Also, whether `grep` recognizes `\d` is platform-dependent; to rule out such issues, use `[0-9]` instead.
- If you use `grep` *without* `-E`, it uses so-called *basic* regular expressions, which require that the quantifier `+` be *escaped* as `\+`; while you could do that, the generally better option is to instead use `grep -E` or to simply invoke `grep` as `egrep` in order to use *extended* regexes, which mostly behave like regular expressions in other languages.
- `.`, when intended to be a literal, should be `\`-escaped in a regex (which you did in one of your attempts).
- The `-1` option of `ls` is implied when `ls` is not outputting to a terminal.
- `grep` uses *substring* matching by default, so use `-x` to match against the *entire* input line (alternatively, use the anchors `^` and `$`) so as to rule out filenames that match the expression but have an additional extension.

Thus, a corrected version of the original command is:

```
 ls | egrep -x 'ifrontThermal64\.[0-9]+'
```

As an aside: there's no point in enclosing your commands in parentheses; you'll needlessly create subshells (unless they're optimized away, but the point is that they're not needed).

Comment: You could just use `{5}` instead of repeating yourself. Also, it's a good idea to escape the `.`.

Comment: @KendallFrey: This is a _glob_ (wildcard expression), not a _regex_. Intervals (bounds) such as `{5}` do not work, and `.` is not a special character.

Comment: Oh, I haven't used grep much, and I thought it used regex. :S

Comment: @KendallFrey: `grep` _does_ use regexes (so-called basic ones by default, extended ones when `grep` is invoked with `-E` or as `egrep`), but my globbing solution is based on _shell pathname expansion_, which uses _globs_ (a.k.a. [filename] patterns, wildcard expression), which are only _distantly_ related to regexes, with some fundamental differences.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Unless you still see something wrong with my answer and comments, I suggest we both remove our comments so as to avoid distracting future readers - once I see your comments removed, I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex with `egrep`, which uses extended regex

```
ifrontThermal64.\d+$
```

The `$` is an anchor identifying end of a string.

For your case, no need to follow the step `ls`->`egrep`->plot.
You can use

```
find . -name 'ifrontThermal64.\d+$' -exec plot {} \;
```